# Creating a URL based on data executed through search facility

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a search bar on my index page, this search bar allows users to search for the restaurants that are in their area by inputting their postal code(UK). I am trying to create a URL string which includes the area name and postal code based on the postal code entered into the search bar.

I currently have a query (works successfully no errors), which indeed prints out the area name the restaurant is in, but just not the postcode, I am not sure why one part of my code is working, but the other is not (doesn't work 100% of the time). However, i  Was wondering if someone could point me into the right direction, as i have no idea how to go forward.

```
 $c_name='';
 $search = '';
 $_POST['search'] = $search;

if(isset($_POST['search'],$_POST['feed_me'])){
     $search= $_POST['search'];


$select_pcode=mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT Rest_Details.Resturant_ID, Rest_Details.City_name, Delivery_Pcode.Pcode 
 FROM Rest_Details INNER JOIN Delivery_Pcode
 ON Delivery_Pcode.Restaurant_ID=Rest_Details.Resturant_ID
 WHERE Delivery_Pcode.Pcode LIKE '%".$search."%'");

 echo var_dump($select_pcode);    
 while($row_pcode=  mysqli_fetch_array($select_pcode)){
 $c_name = $row_pcode['City_name']; 

 }

 <form id ="Form" method="POST" action="Area_Rest_page.php?Area=<?php echo $c_name ?>&Postcode=<?php echo $_POST['search']?>">
```

**I have tried**

- Saving POST into a session
- using $search instead of post in the URL string

It is successfully connected to the DB and dbc has been defined further up the page.

Comment: make sure in both tables Restaurant_ID's exist. you are using INNER join. so if Restaurant_ID is empty in one table it won't return any results. Try LEFT JOIN.

Comment: because the variables are in the action URI iits get not post

Comment: @zenwarrior yeah thats the first thing i checked they do

Comment: @Dagon the method is post, the action is go to ... page

Comment: is the above page 'Area_Rest_page.php' ?

Comment: @Dagon No sorry, it is the index page, i am trying to create a url string to direct to the Area_rest_page